# Stored procedure with more than 1 select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables, Table A and Table B. I have to display values from A as follows:

```
select * from A
where EntityId = 26039 and EntityTypeId = 'REQUEST'
```

Then, from B I want to retrieve values as follows:

```
select OrderRequestTaskId from B
where OrderRequestId = 26039
```

This might give 0 or more OrderRequestTaskId. If this query returns OrderRequestTaskId values of 1,2,3 then I want to display them from table A as follows:

```
select * from A
where  (EntityId = 1 and EntityTypeId = 'TASK')
or  (EntityId = 2 and EntityTypeId = 'TASK')
or (EntityId = 3 and EntityTypeId = 'TASK')
```

In short the select statement will now be as follows:

```
select * from A
where (EntityId = 26039 and EntityTypeId = 'REQUEST')
 or (EntityId = 1 and EntityTypeId = 'TASK' )
or ( EntityId = 2 and EntityTypeId = 'TASK')
or( EntityId = 3 and EntityTypeId = 'TASK')
```

I am not sure how to do this in a stored procedure so that I get all the 4 rows as an output. Can I store the output from the statement

```
select OrderRequestTaskId from B
where OrderRequestId = 26039
```

and then use it to build the final select statement?

Comment: What database platform is this for?

Comment: @ OldProgrammer. I apologize. Its SQL Server

Comment: I'm not understanding your questions, are you asking how to return multiple result sets from a stored procedure (which I wouldn't advise) or how to return a result set from a stored procedure? Do you have a result set format that you are looking for, specifically?

Comment: This will probably help: [Join Fundamentals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use InnerJoin 
it would look like

```
select a.* from TableA a
Inner Join TableB b 
on a.EntityID=b.OrderRequestId
```

--where conditions if any

```
where OrderRequestId = 26039
```